# Google Assistant Basic card body text is clickable

Tags: actions-on-google

While creating a basic card for Google action without image and button, text body only, see below code, I found the formattedText is clickable and it opens a blank browser window.

```
{
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
        }
      ],
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "Title",
                "displayText": "Title"
              }
            },
            {
              "basicCard": {
                "title": "",
                "subtitle": "",
                "formattedText": "Body Text"
              }
            }
          ],
          "suggestions": [
            {
              "title": "A"
            },
            {
              "title": "B"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "isInSandbox": false
}
```

Comment: What devices (Nest hub smart display, android phone or simulator) did you test this on that the body is clickable? Does this behave the same across all of those surfaces?
Please share a screenshot or a picture of that device, it can me further assist you.

Comment: This happens on android phone or iPhone, not on simulator. We don't have this display on hub, so I am not sure if this issue happens on hub no not.